# How to Undo More than Once in Excel for Mac?

Tags: macos, ms-office, undo-redo

I am using Excel for Mac version 16.28 and don't see how I would be able to Undo (<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Z</kbd>) more than once as after undoing once a second undo will just undo the first undo and I have the state I started out with.

This doesn't seem to be an issue for other people.

Is there a setting to allow a deeper undo-redo chain in Excel for Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you actually tried?

As I have used <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> multiple times on formulae I have edited several times and it steps back through the changes sequentially. Even changes sheets as necessary.

On version 16.29 & 365, the help file says 100 actions can be undone but there are exceptions...

Just tested by entering 0 to 9 in separate cells - <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> goes back through deleting them in the order they were entered.

Comment: Yes, obviously I have tried it... I hope a reinstall will help

Comment: @Ramen just checked the excel for mac help and it says it can undo the last 100 actions but does warn some actions cannot be undone.

Comment: @Ramen - reinstalling is a last resort.  You may have a preference saved that limits your undo buffer to 1 instead of 100.  Reinstalling won’t reset these settings meaning you’ll go through a ton of work for naught.  Take some time and do a little detective work to see where the issue might be.

Comment: This checks out. I would triage before reinstalling - make a new user account on the mac - sign in and do a quick test. That way you’ll know it’s a user preference or not a user preference. Well done everyone

Comment: @Ramen - Also be sure to take a look at the Microsoft Support Document, [Undo, redo, or repeat an action](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Undo-redo-or-repeat-an-action-84BDB9BC-4E23-4F06-BA78-F7B893EB2D28) for more details.

Comment: It's probably time to wipe out the Excel preferences if it's not behaving properly. The new user account will test if the prefs are damaged. If the new user works, the preferences are likely the culprit. Check Microsoft's guide here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/975724/excel-for-mac-error-the-application-microsoft-excel-quit-unexpectedly

Comment: Hey, you all were right, the reinstall of Office did not help but deleting the preferences did! Undoing now works fine again, thank you all...

Comment: @Ramen glad you got it sorted, cheers!